# Kinect One & Unity - BodyIndexSource frame issue, drawing a "body-shadow" using the BodyIndexSource

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect, texture2d

Alright so to explain myself better:

**Goal:** Making "shadow figures" in Unity
**Using:** Kinect One, Unity, C#

I am using the Windows Example source that they provide for Unity.

---

Basically what I did is make a BodyIndexSourceManager.cs and a BodyIndexSourceView.cs the same way they made the Color/Depth/Infrared/BodySource data show in unity. I don't see the issue, but that's also because I've never worked with Byte-data in depth and there's little documented on what kind of data is actually received from the BodyIndexSource stream.

---

Example codes:

```
 public class BodyIndexSourceManager : MonoBehaviour
    {

    public int IndexWidth { get; private set; }
    public int IndexHeight { get; private set; }

    private KinectSensor _Sensor;
    private BodyIndexFrameReader _Reader;
    private Texture2D _Texture;
    private byte[] _Data;

    public Texture2D GetTexture()
    {
        return _Texture;
    }
    void Start()
    {
        _Sensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();
        if (_Sensor != null)
        {
            _Reader = _Sensor.BodyIndexFrameSource.OpenReader();
            var frameDesc = _Sensor.BodyIndexFrameSource.FrameDescription;
            IndexWidth = frameDesc.Width;
            IndexHeight = frameDesc.Height;
            _Texture = new Texture2D(frameDesc.Width, frameDesc.Height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
            if (!_Sensor.IsOpen)
            {
                _Sensor.Open();
            }
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (_Reader != null)
        {
            var frame = _Reader.AcquireLatestFrame();
            if (frame != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("frame not null");
                frame.CopyFrameDataToArray(_Data);
                _Texture.LoadRawTextureData(_Data);
                _Texture.Apply();
                frame.Dispose();
                frame = null;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (_Reader != null)
        {
            _Reader.Dispose();
            _Reader = null;
        }
        if (_Sensor != null)
        {
            if (_Sensor.IsOpen)
            {
                _Sensor.Close();
            }
            _Sensor = null;
        }
    }
    }
```

Next class:

```
    public class BodyIndexSourceView : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject BodyIndexSourceManager;
    private BodyIndexSourceManager _bodyIndexManager;

    void Start()
    {
        gameObject.renderer.material.SetTextureScale("_MainTex", new Vector2(-1, 1));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (BodyIndexSourceManager == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _bodyIndexManager = BodyIndexSourceManager.GetComponent<BodyIndexSourceManager>();
        if (_bodyIndexManager == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        gameObject.renderer.material.mainTexture = _bodyIndexManager.GetTexture();
    }
    }
```

I am probably just doing the wrong thing or overseeing something.
Hopefully someone can show me some insight so I can continue! ^_^ Thanks in advance for any response given.

**Summary:**
If you know what the best approach is to draw "only" the pixel-data of tracked bodies into Unity through Kinect One, please let me know or tell me what I am doing wrong for the start @ the code given above.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I found out the main issue why it didn't work.
The BodyIndexSource stream is always in COMBINATION with the DepthSource.

---

So in short:

The Start() method requires a MultiSourceReader, then the Update() method "dissects" the _reader.AcquireLatestFrame() into DepthFrame and BodyIndexFrame.
Without the DepthFrame you won't be able to get values from the BodyIndexFrame. Or at least, that seems to be the case.

Then you "simply" fill in the logic to actually write to a Texture2D and voila, you have something useable in Unity3D.